# How to create a copy of useFetch inside a custom hook?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to create a hook for multiple use, but I get the behavior not the one that I expect

/composables/fetch.ts

```js
export const useFetchWithErrorHandler = async (url: string, options?: FetchOptions) => {
  const route = useRoute();
  const { API_BASE_URL, API_PREFIX } = useRuntimeConfig();

  console.log(url, options);

  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const response = await useFetch(API_PREFIX + url, {
      ...options,
      baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
      initialCache: false,
      async onResponse({ request, response, options }) {
        console.log('[fetch response]', response);
      },
      async onResponseError({ request, response, options }) {
        console.log('[fetch response error]');
      },
    });
    resolve(response);
  });
```

[image]

Only the first request is triggered

```js
const { data: response } = await useFetchWithErrorHandler(`page-1`, {
    pick: ['data'],
});

const { data: response } = await useFetchWithErrorHandler(`page-2`, {
    pick: ['data'],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`useFetch` uses caching to avoid multiple identical requests.

You can disable caching if you set `initialCache: false` in the options, e.g.

```js
useFetch(API_PREFIX + url, {
    ...options,
    initialCache: false,
  }
)
```

Comment: This option does not solve the problem, only one request is made when the page is loaded

Comment: if you use $fetch, then the requests work properly, but I would like to use useFetch to access data, pending, error, refresh

Comment: Please share more code to reproduce then.

Comment: call example added

Comment: added console.log for clarity